# How to open new tab in Chrome Extensions (Manifest v2)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a simple Chrome extension that opens new Chrome tabs on clicking some URLs.
I was using with success a simple in-line javascript

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function LaunchURL(oURL) {
var launchType = localStorage["LS_LaunchType"];           
    switch (launchType) {
        case "TN":
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: oURL });
            break;
        case "WN":
            chrome.windows.create({ url: oURL });
            break;
        default:
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: oURL });
            break;
    }
}
</script>   
...
<a href="javascript:LaunchURL('http://foo.com')">My hyperlink</a>
```

I want to upgrade manifest.json to version 2, but now the in-line script are blocked for security reasons. 
How can I open new tabs? 
I have tried to create a separate javascript file with the previous function, but without success.

Comment: EDIT: After some googling I have found a simple fix: 
    **<a href="http://foo.com" target="blank">My hyperlink</a>** 
works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work correctly in an external javascript file, but you will need remove the script from the anchor tag.  Instead just have the url in the anchor tag and add an event listener in the javascript that prevents the default action.

So in the page you have:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
<a href="http://foo.com">My hyperlink</a>
```

And in external.js you have:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
           LaunchURL(event.currentTarget.href);
           event.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function LaunchURL(oURL) {
        var launchType = localStorage["LS_LaunchType"];           
            switch (launchType) {
                case "TN":
                    chrome.tabs.create({ url: oURL });
                    break;
                case "WN":
                    chrome.windows.create({ url: oURL });
                    break;
                default:
                    chrome.tabs.create({ url: oURL });
                    break;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But still not working. The Chrome-Developer-Console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: anchor is not defined", with reference to line 23 [ **LaunchURL(anchor.href);** ]

Comment: I've edited the answer, so now try `event.currentTarget.href` instead of `anchor.href` that should read it from the click event.